# Can't get data from client on server-side with Ionic and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

This question might have been ansked before, but i can't seem to find the correct answer for it. I'm working on a Ionic project where i've created another project with Node.js and express.js to handle all my http requests. Both are running on localhost at the moment. When i'm trying to send some data from my client-side to to server-side, the data that i'm getting from the request looks like this when i console.log(req.body):

`{ '{"username":"hello@hello.com"}': '' }`

I tryed both req.body[username] and so on to get the data, but then it just gets undefined.

My controller for handling the http request looks like this:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  var username = $scope.username;
  console.log($scope.data.username);
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/users',
    data: username,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});
```

Html element

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.username" name="name">
```

Server-side API looks like this:

```
router.post('/users', function (req, res) { 
    var username = req.body;

    var newUser = new User({
        username: username
    })

    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
        return res.json(200, newUser);
    });
});
```

Server.js bodyparser included

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: can you tell us what username stores in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object have keys and values

```
{ key: value }
```

The object on the body is beeing sent in some wrong way since you're sending a object with they key '{"username":"hello@hello.com"}' which has the value ''.

I would recomend fixing how you're posting to your nodejs/express server. But you can get the value by some hacks. Like this.

```
 const body = {'{"username":"hello@hello.com"}': '' }

 const keys = Object.keys(body);
 const parsed = JSON.parse(keys[0]);
 console.log(parsed.username);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wejh0fsk/2/

Edit: So what I am doing here is getting all the keys of the object. There's only one key '{"username":"hello@hello.com"}'. Since that key is a string I am parsing it to get a object. Now I have a object

```
  { username: 'hello@hello.com' }
```

And finally I'm logging out the username.

The right solution would to fix how your sending your data to the express server.

I don't quite understand your controller. Your ng-model is data.username but then you're putting

```
var username = $scope.username
```

Which should be

```
var username = $scope.data.username // (that's at least what you're binding to in your view)
```

Also you want to send an object with the post, not  just the value

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  var username = $scope.username;
  console.log($scope.data.username);
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/users',
    data: { username: username },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});
```

I am not sure on express parsers but I don't know why you're calling the bodyparser twice. The first one should be enough.